# completion of metric space comes from the extension of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

An argument in the book Carother's Real Analysis.

In the book the author first proved a theorem:

> Theorem 8.16. Let $D$ be dense in $M$, let $N$ be complete, and let $f : D
>  \to  N$ be uniformly continuous. Then, $f$ extends uniquely to a uniformly continuous map $F : M \to N$, defined on all of  $M$. Moreover,
> if $f$ is an isometry, then so is the extension $F$.

Then he stated a corollary, as follows:

> Corollary 8.17. Completions are unique (up to isometry). That is, if
> $M_1$ and $M_2$ are completions of  $M$, then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isometric.

To me, I don't see why Corollary 8.17 is a corollary of Theorem 8.16. Theorem 8.16 just proved an extension of function, not the completion of a metric space. Maybe extra work needs to be done, but this is not obvious to me.

About the completion, the author proved the following:

> Theorem 7.18. If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are completions of  $M$, then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are
> isometric.

EDIT: I think here the author meant the result of theorem 8.16 can be used in the proof of Theorem 7.18 to construct an isometry there(in the proof of Theorem 7.18), which leads to a quicker proof of the completions are isometrically isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are completions of $M$, i.e. they are complete metric spaces that have dense subspaces $M'$ and $M''$ respectively, isomorphic to $M$ via isomorphisms $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Then we can define map $h: M' \to M_2$ as $h = g \circ f^{-1}$. Then $h$ is isometry. Applying theorem 8.16, substituting $D = M'$, $N = M_1$, $f = h$, we get $F$ - isometric extension of $h$ that is defined on all $M_1$. Thus, $F$ is isometry between $M_1$ and some subset of $M_2$.

Now, for $x \in M_2$ let $M'' \ni x_n \to x$ (for this we need $M''$ to be dense in $M_2$). Then $F(\lim_n F^{-1}(x_n)) = x$, and thus image of $F$ is the whole $M_2$, and so $F$ is isometry between $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: I think you meant "the whole $M_2$" not "the whole $M''$".

Comment: And $F(\lim_n F^{-1}(x_n)) = x$ since $F$ is isometry, so we can interchange limit and $F$. Moreover, for any $n$, $F^{-1}(x_n)$ is an element in $M'$, hence they are in $M_1$ and their limit is also in $M_1$. So Actually we found an elemnet in $M_1$ whose image is $x$, as required. Just for clarification.